# Using dataframe operations, determine how long, in days a given name in the dataset lived

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataset in which I would like to solve the following problem:

> Using dataframe operations, determine how long, in days, Ulysses S.
>   Grant lived.

[image]

The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
grant_days = president_data.get('Name') == 'Ulysses S. Grant'
grant_days.iloc[0]['Life Years']
```

I am attempting to isolate the life years after selecting Ulysses grant. The ['Life years'] throws in the following error:

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 grant_days = president_data.get('Name') == 'Ulysses S. Grant'
>   ----> 2 grant_days.iloc[0]['Life Years']
>
> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Start instead with: `president_data[president_data['Name'] == 'Ulysses S. Grant']`

Comment: Couldn't you just use the number on the last column "Life Days"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of indexed data, you can use `.loc` accessors like this:

```
grant_days = president_data.loc['Ulysses S. Grant', 'Life Years']
```

Comment: 'presidents' is the indexed data and 'president_data' is the non-indexed data. nice to now know the .loc/.iloc for the indexed data.